Simple AND gate implementation on Sipeed Tang Primer 25K not working | Gowin FPGA
I have this basic VHDL code for AND gate, I wanted to test the new board I recently got. It hast two on board buttons and wanted to light an external LED connecting to pins from 2x20 pin connector; also tried with pmod pins.
The board gets programmed but it's always sending 3.3V on the outputs.
Here's the VHDL code:
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity prueba_compuertaAND is
    port(
    boton_1 : in std_logic; --button 1
    boton_2 : in std_logic; --button 2
    led : out std_logic);
end entity prueba_compuertaAND;

architecture RTL of prueba_compuertaAND is
begin
    led <= boton_1 and boton_2;
end RTL;

Also here's the floor planner view:

And here's the board schematic for the pins I used to connect the LED (on breadboard):

I tried with K2 pin from the 2x20 connector.

And with A10 pin form pmod J5.
Also important, the schematic for buttons:

Some ideas on what may be going on? Also I'm totally new on Gowin EDA, and kind of new on working with FPGA devices.

Your buttons don't seem to do anything useful unless there are pulldowns enabled on your input pins.  Your screenshot of the FloorPlanner unfortunately doesn't show the pull settings for the pins since it is cut off on the right side. Either show a better screenshot or copy/paste your .cst file.

@SteKulov thanks it was Pull mode. I didn’t know I had to configure those.

OK, I'll post a proper answer when I get the chance.

When you're writing your FPGA code for the button inputs, you need to understand how the buttons on your hardware work.  Let's just look at the first one:

The H11_IOT3A_S1 is the node that goes to your FPGA pin.  If you look through the rest of the schematics there are no other components (either series or parallel) in the path of the FPGA, so this simplifies things.
We can analyze the voltage of this node, assuming the FPGA is not there, for both ON and OFF states.  When the switch is OFF, only the protection diode D2 and filter cap C1 are connected.  This means that in DC, this node is pretty much "floating" and is highly influenced by leakages through the diode and the capacitor (and the FPGA pin when it's there).  So the voltage at this node is unknown.  When the switch is ON, the 3.3V goes through the 100ohm resistor which is plenty to overcome the leakages mentioned.  So the voltage at this node is now 3.3V.
Having the switch result in an unknown voltage in one state and a 3.3V voltage in the other state is not very useful.  You need to connect something else to this node to utilize the button properly.
Now, add the FPGA pin back into the mix.  You can configure the "Pull Mode" for each FPGA pin using the "FloorPlanner" in the GOWIN software.  Here is where the column is located in the "I/O Constraints" tab.

The Pull Mode can be one of 4 options: UP, DOWN, NONE, and KEEPER.
UP means an internal pullup resistor gets connected to the pin.  The value (or loose range of values) for this pullup can usually be found in the FPGA datasheet.  In the GW5A-25K datasheet it's given as a current value, so you can take your VCCIO voltage divided by this current to get an equivalent resistance.  For example with a VCCIO of 3.3V and the "Medium" strength pullup of 150µA you get 3.3V/150µA=22kΩ.

DOWN means the same thing except with a pulldown resistor instead of a pullup resistor.
NONE means nothing additional is connected to the pin.  It's roughly equivalent to the FPGA pin not being there, but not exactly since the FPGA can introduce its own leakages.  We also call this setting "HIGH-Z" or "high impedance".
KEEPER means the "bus keeper" (also called "bus hold") circuit is active.  This is mainly for bi-directional buses, but works for any circuit can be tri-stated (i.e. put into "HIGH-Z" state).  It's like a mix between NONE and UP/DOWN.  You can find more info about it here.

If you notice in the above "FloorPlanner" screenshot, the default Pull Mode for each pin is UP.  So if you leave this default and you analyze both states of the button, you'll notice that the voltage at the pin is 3.3V for each case.  This is why your AND gate wasn't working; both button states produce the same voltage!  So like the NONE setting, the UP setting is not useful for your button hardware.
You need to use the DOWN setting for this particular button hardware.  When the switch is OFF, the pin is pulled down to 0V (logic LOW) via the internal pulldown resistor.  When the switch is ON, the 3.3V through the 100Ω resistor is able to overpower the 22kΩ internal pulldown resistor.  To be more exact, this would result in ~3.285V (3.3V through voltage divider of 100Ω and 22kΩ) at the pin indicating a logic HIGH.  Therefore, this configuration is what you want.
